# Facebook user_link returned from Graph API, but leads to "Content Not Found" page

Tags: firebase, facebook-login, facebook-authentication

My app requests the user_link permission like this:

```
    loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setPermissions("email", "user_link", "user_location");
```

And in the Graph API callback, the link field does contain a URL. However, for some users, selecting the link leads to the "Content Not Found" page. Why is this happening for some users but not all?

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that this only happens with test users! When Facebook tested my app, they used a name of a real user, but the email address was for a test user. Faked me out totally. I tested with an unfriended user and was able to see their page without a problem.

Comment: I don't understand how you managed to make it work. For me it still works only for freinds, for not friends it gives a page not found. can you let me know please?

Comment: @Vladi Hi, where you able to access other profiles than friends? I think I have the exact same problem as you. I can't get it to work. I'm getting app_scoped_user links from the API, I have the user_link permission and it just doesn't make any sense.